# PHP OOP: Issues with properties and extended class

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have this PHP script:

```
<?php

class Aaa
{
    protected $var = null;

    public function performSomething()
    {
        $this->var = 'Now we have a string, not more null value';
        $bbb = New Bbb();
        $bbb->powerOnYou();

    }
}


class Bbb extends Aaa
{
    public function powerOnYou()
    {
        var_dump($this->var);
        // this dump "NULL" and not string
    }
}


$aaa = New Aaa();
$aaa->performSomething();
```

How you can note this class will "var_dump" everytime NULL, and not the string.

Of course I need to output the string.

This is also the sandbox link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6cd253e1945e78f114749be55ffc5f88ab44dd42

Thank you

Comment: Because you have two objects?! Which doesn't have to do anything with each other. Every instance of a class is a **completely** new fresh copy of the class definition.

Comment: Because this is only an example. It could be, for example, a Controller that give "control" to other Controllers.... based for example on a REST api...

Comment: @DavidKmenta And to solve my "code"/"issues" ? How I need to change my code? Thank you...

Comment: 1. Create an instance of `Bbb`, which extends from `Aaa`, means you can use all functionalities. E.g. `$bbb = new Bbb();` instead of `$aaa = New Aaa();` 2. According to that change the method call from: `$aaa->performSomething();` to `$bbb->performSomething();` 3. Don't create a new instance of a class as you did here: `$bbb = New Bbb();
        $bbb->powerOnYou();`, just simply call the method from your object which you already have: `$bbb->powerOnYou();` (3.1. From outside of the class definitions)(3.2. FYI: `var` is a keyword in PHP so I wouldn't recommend it to use it as class property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `$var` is an instance variable, not a class variable. That means, every instance of your class has its own copy of it.

You create an instance of class `Aaa` and set `$aaa`'s copy of `$var` to `'Now we have a string, not more null value'`. However, inside `performSomething()`, you create a completely new instance of class `Bbb`, which has its own copy of `$var`. Since you did not set `$bbb`'s `$var`, it is `null` when you output it.

Have a look at this code and try to understand it; I did not have the opportunity to test it since I am at work right now, but it should give you your desired output:

```
<?php

class Aaa
{
    protected $var = null;

    public function powerOnYou()
    {
        var_dump($this->var);
    }
}


class Bbb extends Aaa
{
    public function performSomething()
    {
        $this->var = 'Now we have a string, not more null value';
        $this->powerOnYou();
    }
}


$bbb = New Bbb();
$bbb->performSomething();
```